# Writing a class / object using algorithmic in LaTeX

Tags: algorithmic

I am aware, similar questions have been asked but i can't find any that have used the package 'algorithmic' so I'm asking.

I want to write a class in latex, as i've been using the algorithmic package i would like to stick with it if possible. i can't figure out how to do so? Just simply, it should be a block of code starting with 'class'

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DG' I don't really have a minimal working example because i don't know what to do

Comment: You should provide a compilable document that and a detailed description of what you want to do. The current state of your question does not permit a detailed answer. However, read the `algorithmic` documentation, especially section 4 "Custom algorithmic blocks", there you will find the commands needed to define a `class` block.